# Inline fontFamily not working in React / Next.js 9

Tags: reactjs, jsx, next.js

### Problem Description

I have a Next.js application and am trying to use in-line styles to change the font family of a `<p>` element. This isn't working, but if I try applying a `color: 'red'` style, it works just fine.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
export default () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p style={{ fontFamily: 'system-ui' }}>Hello from Next.js</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

### Expected Result

Font family of `<p>` element changes to `system-ui`.

### Actual Result

Text is rendered, but the font family stays as the browser default.

### package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "9.4.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1"
  }
```

### Node Version

```
> node -v
v14.5.0
```

Browser: Firefox 77, Windows 10

**Question**: Why isn't my fontFamily inline style applying correctly?

Comment: There is no default font-family called 'sanserif` in CSS.  It should be `sans-serif`.

Comment: My bad, I meant to post about `system-ui` not working. I've edited the question.

Comment: Generally, that font-family would be used in a reset or some other base site or page styles along with a collection of others.  The `system-ui` works in some browsers but not all.  https://caniuse.com/#search=system-ui

Comment: @jme11 Thanks, I spend most of my time in Google Chrome, which works fine, but for my training work, I use Firefox. That appears to be my issue. Cheers for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a typo there. Try `sans-serif` instead of `sanserif`.

Also, make sure your web browser supports the `system-ui` font at https://caniuse.com/#feat=font-family-system-ui

Comment: Thanks, good callout. I actually am having issues specifically with `system-ui` then. For some reason, that doesn't work, but `sans-serif` does. I edited the question.

Comment: I tried using inline-style for ```system-ui``` font family in codesandbox. It seems to work fine (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-boilerplate-ofcpg?file=/src/index.js). Can you check if your browser supports it in the first place?
https://caniuse.com/#feat=font-family-system-ui (this might help you for reference).

Comment: You're right. It was working fine just the other day in Google Chrome, but for my demo work I'm using Firefox. Looks like that is my problem.